# Show "Open with..." dialogue using a command

Tags: command-line, filemanager

Is there a way to show Nautilus' or Thunar's (or whatever) "Open with..." dialogue directly from the commandline? I am using [muCommander](http://mucommander.com) and need to open files with non-default applications once in a while. I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It's not exactly what you want but you could use `path-to-program-of-choice path-to-file`. Example: `/usr/bin/evince ~/Documents/file.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks -- this works OK from the terminal, but I would like to call the dialogue window automatically from muCommander (twin-panel GUI file manager written in Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mimeopen` might be what you search. Use it with the `-d` switch:

```
user@host:~$ mimeopen -d test.txt
Please choose a default application for files of type text/plain

    1) gedit  (gedit)
    2) Other...

use application #2
use command: vi
Opening "test.txt" with vi  (text/plain)
```

You can choose `2` for another application, and then type your command to use (`vi`, in my case). After choosing `vi`, it will be automatically be in the list as first place. So, when typing `mimeopen test.txt` it will open `test.txt` in `vi` without asking. Additionally you can use `mimopen --ask test.txt` this will prompt you for all default applications (`gedit` and in my case also `vi`).

Comment: Thanks very much, that is _almost_ what I need! 

I'd rather like a GUI window that does that, but I can have muCommander open an xterm to run this command. The only drawback is that the xterm window stays open until I close my selected application. 

Is there a way to make mimeopen run the selected application in background?

Comment: I don't know muCommander and never used it. But, when you type `mimeopen somefile` in the run command dialog, it does not open the file with gedit for example?

Comment: Yes it does -- but I need the menu to show first and this means that I need to open a terminal. But `mimeopen` (and the terminal window) stays open till I close my selected application.

But it still seems as close as I can get, thanks :-).